# ¿Como puedo heredar objetos o vectores de un metodo a otro?

Tags: java, array, poo, netbeans, herencia

Buenos dias tengo un codigo en el cual uso polimorfimos y en un metodo estan todos los datos ya definidos y en el otro metodo lo quiero usar para modificar los datos de este metodo anterior, pero no quiero juntar los dos metodos y dejarlos en una sola, que consejos o ayuda me recomienda aplicar, a parte de esto tengo otro problema y es que en el metodo "formas" hay una funcion que dice  "vehiculos[option]=null;", hay lo que quiero es borrar los datos del vector pero al activar esa funcion no hace nada, me podrian ayudar gracias

```
private void autoMovilesNuevos() throws IOException{  //POLIMORFISMOS
     
     PlantillaAuto vehiculos[] = new PlantillaAuto[7];
     
     vehiculos[0] = new PlantillaAuto(2000,4,600000,"RTX500","Rojo","Ferrari","QWE123");
     vehiculos[1] = new PlantillaAuto(2001,2,5000000,"GTX1200","Rojo","Chevorelt","QWT123");
     vehiculos[2] = new PlantillaAuto(2011,4,40000,"RTUX411","Verde","Ford","GHJ123");
     
     vehiculos[3] = new CocheDeportivo("No", "Si", 2020,2,61200000,"UVM123","Rojo","Ferrari","QWR123" );
     vehiculos[4] = new CocheDeportivo("SI", "Si", 2020,2,99900000,"HMQ1344","Negro","Porshe","QASB123" );
     
     vehiculos[5] = new CocheCamioneta(6,2019, 6 ,6912330,"ACV6566","Blanco","Mazda","QGS123" );
     vehiculos[6] = new CocheCamioneta(8,2019, 8 ,1231330,"ACV6566","Marron","Chevrolet","ASD125" );
 }
     
     
    private void formas() {  

     /*
     for(PlantillaAuto i: vehiculos){
         System.out.println(i.toString());
     }
     */
     
     for (int i = 0; i < vehiculos.length; i++) {
         System.out.println("Opcion " + (i+1) + " " + vehiculos[i]);
     }
      
     System.out.println("Ingrese la opcion del coche");
     int option = (Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()))-1;
     System.out.println(vehiculos[option]);
     System.out.println("¿Esta seguro?,(si,no)");
     String sure = br.readLine();
     if (sure.equalsIgnoreCase("si")) {
         for (int i = 0; i < listaCliente.size(); i++) {
             if (listaCliente.get(i).getPresupuesto()<vehiculos[option].getPrecio() ){
                 System.out.println("Poco Presupuesto :c");
                 desplegarMenu();
             } else {
                 System.out.println("Felicidades Disfruta tu ¡Nuevo Coche! ");
                 double dineroPersona = listaCliente.get(i).getPresupuesto();
                 double dineroVehiculo = vehiculos[option].getPrecio();
                 listaCliente.get(i).setPresupuesto(dineroPersona-dineroVehiculo);
                 listaCliente.get(i).setCoche(true);
                 vehiculos[option]=null;  //esto no borra los datos
                 desplegarMenu();
             }
         }
     } else {
         desplegarMenu();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entendí bien quieres que los objetos-datos con que manejas un método1 los puedas usar también en un segundo método2 ¿cierto? Pues yo lo solucionaría poniendo estos objetos-datos fuera del metodo1 y metodo2

```
public class ClaseDatos{
    String[] objetosDatos={"a","b","c"}; 
    public void metodoUno(String[] obj){
        for(int i=0; i<objetosDatos.length; i++)
            objetosDatos[i]=objetosDatos[i].toUpperCase();
    }
    public void metodoDos(String[] obj){
        for(int i=0; i<objetosDatos.length; i++)
            objetosDatos[i]=objetosDatos[i]+".";
    }
}
```

Si quisieras puedes probar esto en un .java distinto en metodo3:

```
public class PruebaClaseDatos{
    public static void main(String[] args){ //main es el metodo3
        ClaseDatos instancia=new ClaseDatos();
        instancia.metodoUno(instancia.objetosDatos);
        instancia.metodoDos(instancia.objetosDatos);
        for(String dato: instancia.objetosDatos)System.out.println(dato);
    }
}
```

La ejecución de PruebaClaseDatos.java Imprimirá:

```
A.
B.
C.
```